# jQuery Selector for children

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

If you click on any heading in the following example, every child is getting another background. Unfortunately, this is not what I want.

I want something like this:
If I click a parent, it'll change the color of every direct(!) child and not the background of other childs of groups inside of it.

I'm currently trying to figure out the correct selector of it but I don't get it.

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.checkbox-parent').on('click', function() {
        var $group = $(this).closest('.checkbox-group');
        var $childs = $group.find('.checkbox-child');

        var checked = this.checked;

        $childs.each(function() {
            $(this).closest('.form-check').css('background-color', checked ? '#ABC' : 'red');
        });
    });

});
```

```css
.form-check {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.checkbox-group {
  background-color: #ABC;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.checkbox-group .checkbox-group {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-parent" id="parent-1" checked="">
    <label for="parent-1"><strong>1 - The parent</strong></label>

    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-1-1" checked=""/>
        <label for="child-1-1">1 - This is an example text.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-1-2" checked="">
        <label for="child-1-2">1 - This is an example text.</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox-group">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-parent" id="parent-2" checked="">
        <label for="parent-2"><strong>2 - The parent</strong></label>

        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-2-1" checked="">
            <label for="child-2-1">2 - This is an example text.</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-2-2" checked="">
            <label for="child-2-2">2 - This is an example text.</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-group">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-parent" id="parent-3" checked="">
            <label for="parent-3"><strong>3 - The parent</strong></label>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-3-1" checked="">
                <label for="child-3-1">3 - This is an example text.</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-3-2" checked="">
                <label for="child-3-2">3 - This is an example text.</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I only changed your selector from

```
$group.find('.checkbox-child')
```

to

```
$group.find('> .form-check')
```

With that you won't need the `closest` call in your `each` anymore either

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.checkbox-parent').on('click', function() {
        var $group = $(this).closest('.checkbox-group');
        var $childs = $group.find('> .form-check');

        var checked = this.checked;

        $childs.each(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', checked ? '#ABC' : 'red');
        });
    });

});
```

```css
.form-check {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.checkbox-group {
  background-color: #ABC;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.checkbox-group .checkbox-group {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-parent" id="parent-1" checked="">
    <label for="parent-1"><strong>1 - The parent</strong></label>

    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-1-1" checked=""/>
        <label for="child-1-1">1 - This is an example text.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-1-2" checked="">
        <label for="child-1-2">1 - This is an example text.</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox-group">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-parent" id="parent-2" checked="">
        <label for="parent-2"><strong>2 - The parent</strong></label>

        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-2-1" checked="">
            <label for="child-2-1">2 - This is an example text.</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-2-2" checked="">
            <label for="child-2-2">2 - This is an example text.</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox-group">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-parent" id="parent-3" checked="">
            <label for="parent-3"><strong>3 - The parent</strong></label>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-3-1" checked="">
                <label for="child-3-1">3 - This is an example text.</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-3-2" checked="">
                <label for="child-3-2">3 - This is an example text.</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how about if those child's are inside other containers/divs? If so, ">" can't be used.

Comment: Yeah but didn't you state specifically in your question: `of every direct(!) child`? Basically you need to root your query search in something. You could also assign a data attribute with a level number and then just select by that level for each section.

Answer (score 0):

Since the children are children of siblings of the parent, use `.siblings` on the parent to get to the `.form-check`s, and from each of those, use `.find` to get to the children:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.checkbox-parent').on('click', function() {
    const $childs = $(this).siblings('.form-check').find('.checkbox-child');

    var checked = this.checked;

    $childs.each(function() {
      $(this).closest('.form-check').css('background-color', checked ? '#ABC' : 'red');
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.form-check {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.checkbox-group {
  background-color: #ABC;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.checkbox-group .checkbox-group {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-group">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-parent" id="parent-1" checked="">
  <label for="parent-1"><strong>1 - The parent</strong></label>

  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-1-1" checked="" />
    <label for="child-1-1">1 - This is an example text.</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-1-2" checked="">
    <label for="child-1-2">1 - This is an example text.</label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-parent" id="parent-2" checked="">
    <label for="parent-2"><strong>2 - The parent</strong></label>

    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-2-1" checked="">
      <label for="child-2-1">2 - This is an example text.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-2-2" checked="">
      <label for="child-2-2">2 - This is an example text.</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox-group">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-parent" id="parent-3" checked="">
      <label for="parent-3"><strong>3 - The parent</strong></label>

      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-3-1" checked="">
        <label for="child-3-1">3 - This is an example text.</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-child" id="child-3-2" checked="">
        <label for="child-3-2">3 - This is an example text.</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```